# Recurrence Relation that has a square root

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I can't seem to solve this recurrence relation found in a revision sheet:

> $$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(\sqrt{n}) + n.$$

Comment: Assuming this is a sequence indexed by the positive integers, what do you do if $n$ is not a perfect square? I think this question needs more detail.

Comment: If it's indexed in the intergers, there's also a problem if n is odd.

Comment: We have that $T_0=0$ if that helps

Comment: I assume you want an asymptotic bound on $T$. I believe that since $\sqrt{n}=\mathcal{O}(n/3)$ we can say that $T(n)\leq T(n/2)+T(n/3)+n$ which gives $T(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: @Rhys Hughes, $T_0=0$ follows from the equation: for $n=0$, we gave $T(0)=T(0)+T(0)+0$.

Comment: @TodorMarkov, exactly, that's where I got it